# In Highcharts, how to implement a 3D-spline type of chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

According to Highcharts' website, Highcharts does not natively support 3D line or spline.

However to achieve `3D - line` chart, there is a very simple workaround, which is adding `lineWidth: 1` to either each series or to `plotingOptions.series` with `type` set to `scatter`. But how do we implement a `3D - spline`? Can any body help please?

By the way it is very not understandable why Highcharts doesn't natively support them, I believe they are very commonly used, inluding `3D - area`.

Here is a fiddle of Highcharts `3D - line`:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/kxafwcas/

Comment: I would strongly caution you about working with three-dimensional charts in general, as it is very easy to create what's called a "misleading graph" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misleading_graph). A line/spline chart plotted in three-dimensional space would be difficult for a user to figure out precisely where each point was plotted relative to the axes. I know there's a tooltip in your demo (which is a clever idea), but all points in a chart need to be readable at a glance.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support 3d-spline. To request a new Highcharts feature, you could post a suggestion on [Highcharts' UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general), or vote for the ones that are already registered.

Comment: @brightmatrix Thanks for the heads up, I do notice it some times in developing. Unfortunately, currently I'm working on a project to use Highcharts to render charts which were rendered using an old server side charting library, I need to reproduce the charts as same as the old way, and 3D: line, spline, area were all supported.

Comment: @Feedfedfat Thanks for hearing me out and for sharing your project requirements. Have you tried an area chart in 3D with a transparent fill color and line markers? That could bring you closer to what you're trying to replicate from that old system.

Comment: @brightmatrix Not quite sure about it. I've tried area chart in 3D, but only the frame (the axes system) is displaying in 3D, the area chart itself is still in 2D, and will not change with the alpha and beta changing.

Comment: @Feedfedfat Oh, I see ... it seems the area is, in essence, still considered a line, so it fails to get three dimensions as you witnessed.